# Why Trigger.new is a list and not a sObject?

Tags: apex, trigger

I'd like to understand why `Trigger.new` is a list and not a sObject.

And if I do:

```
insert record1;
insert record2;
```

Will both `record1` and `record2` be in the same `Trigger.new`?

Comment: Why would it be a single SObject? We can perform DML on multiple records at a time, and while a list can hold a single SObject record the opposite is not true (a single SObject cannot hold multiple SObject records).

Comment: Thank you, Derek. And what about the second question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the API was first introduced, it did not have a bulk option. You could only ever create, update, delete, or undelete one record at a time. In the initial version of Apex, `Trigger.new` was indeed a single sObject that was a concrete type.

Later, for performance reasons, Salesforce created bulk API calls, so you could update records in batches of up to 100. Salesforce added the ability for `Trigger.new` to be a `List<sObject>`, but you had to opt-in with the `bulk` keyword. During the transition period, `Trigger.new` was an `sObject` without `bulk`, and was a `List<sObject>` of a concrete type with this keyword.

This is still supported today:

```
trigger CheckAccountName on Account bulk (before insert) {
  for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.Name.length() < 3) {
      record.Name.addError('Please use at least three characters');
    }
  }
}
```

This has no effect in the modern compiler, but is accepted for backwards compatibility. The requirement for the bulk opt-in was removed within a couple of releases of the bulk opt-in, because the single-fire mode for triggers was permanently removed, and any single-fire triggers were permanently disabled until they were updated to support the bulk-fire mode.

Even later, the limit per API call was updated from 100 to 200. Older triggers would be broken up into chunks of 100 for backwards compatibility. These APIs are now deprecated, so this chunking behavior has probably also been removed.

As far as the second question, every DML operation gets its own trigger context, so your trigger would fire twice. To combine the updates, make a list:

```
insert new sObject[] { record1, record2 };
```

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your question is likely not answerable using public sources (i.e. we'd need a Salesforce employee to give a definitive answer). An educated guess might be something along the lines of *because triggers are a database construct, and triggers in Apex are just an interface Salesforce provides to create a database trigger behind the scenes*.

In other words, my educated guess is that database triggers work on collections of records. So that was a constraint that Salesforce needed to work with when designing/developing Apex as a language.

Comment: I'm actually experienced enough to know why.

Answer (score 2):

As Derek F said, DML operations can be performed on multiple records at one time, so that's why `Trigger.new` is a list.

For your second question: Each separate `insert` you do in Apex will cause its own trigger to run. So in your example, the trigger would run twice. First, `Trigger.new` will be a list with one record (`record1`) and then it will be another list with one record (`record2`).